# Sort array of objects which is having a key as a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a following array of objects:

```
   [    
  {
        html: "<span class="email">",
        startOffset: "109"
        type: "Email"
    },
    {
        html: "<span class="email">",
        endOffset: "139"
        type: "Email"
    },
    {
        html: "<span class="email">",
        startOffset: "149"
        type: "Email"
    },
    {
        html: "<span class="email">",
        startOffset: "155"
        type: "Email"
    },
     {
        html: "<span class="email">",
        endOffset: "160"
        type: "Email"
    },
    {
        html: "<span class="email">",
        startOffset: "0"
        type: "Email"
    },
    {
        html: "<span class="email">",
        endOffset: "15"
        type: "Email"
    },
]
```

Now, Here I want to sort this using the startoffset and endoffset parameter in ascending order.
whichever is first should be at the first in newly created array of objects.

So for this I have used following logic

```
newJSON.sort(function (a, b) {
            var aVal = a.startOffset ? a.startOffset : a.endOffset;
            var bVal = b.startOffset ? b.startOffset : b.endOffset;
            return aVal - bVal;
          });
          console.log("before sorting==>", newJSON);
          jsonDataArray.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.startOffset - b.startOffset;
          });
```

Now, Here it is sorting but when the start offset is 0 then it is not sorting in the proper way. So, Can any one suggest me where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Whats your opinion on that dirty unreadable piece of code where you declare your array?

Comment: Yes I will change this sorry for that

Comment: @MedetTleukabilulyplease check

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understood your problem.
This worked for me:

```
var newJSON = [{
    html: "<span class=\"email\">",
    startOffset: "109",
    type: "email"
  },
  {
    html: "<span class=\"email\">",
    endOffset: "139",
    type: "email"
  },
  {
    html: "<span class=\"email\">",
    startOffset: "149",
    type: "email"
  },
  {
    html: "<span class=\"email\">",
    startOffset: "155",
    type: "email"
  },
  {
    html: "<span class=\"email\">",
    endOffset: "160",
    type: "email"
  },
  {
    html: "<span class=\"email\">",
    startOffset: "0",
    type: "email"
  },
  {
    html: "<span class=\"email\">",
    endOffset: "15",
    type: "email"
  },
]

console.log(newJSON.map(i => i.startOffset || i.endOffset))

newJSON.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aVal = a.startOffset != undefined ? parseInt(a.startOffset) : parseInt(a.endOffset);
  var bVal = b.startOffset != undefined ? parseInt(b.startOffset) : parseInt(b.endOffset);
  return aVal - bVal;
});

console.log(newJSON.map(i => i.startOffset || i.endOffset))
```

Got the following:

```
["109", "139", "149", "155", "160", "0", "15"]
["0", "15", "109", "139", "149", "155", "160"]
```

Regards,
Vincent

Comment: Okay, I think that might be the issue. So is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Assuming that a is always defined and just the property startOffset is missing, you can write: a.startOffset !== undefined ? a.startOffset : a.endOffset

Comment: Thing is I don't really understand your need. You wanna sort according to which field? startOffset or endOffset?

Comment: Both the fields .

Comment: If I use this thing on the bval then it is working fine for me .

Comment: will it be okay If I use this on bval only ?

Comment: Can you please try with `a.startOffset !== undefined ? parseInt(a.startOffset) : parseInt(a.endOffset)`

Comment: actually a object does not have that startoffset may be because of that

Answer (score 0):

Check for null or undefined values:

```
function isNullOrUndefined(k){ 
     return typeof(k) === 'undefined' || k === null;
}

var aVal = isNullOrUndefined(a.startOffset) ? a.startOffset : a.endOffset;
var bVal = isNullOrUndefined(b.startOffset) ? b.startOffset : b.endOffset;
```

Comment: After using this, It is not sorting in a proper order.As it was doing previously.

Comment: Can you please provide the values/scenario in which it is failing? Converting to proper number `a.endOffset` as `0` can  help.

Comment: okay .. The json which I have given there there is one value 0 for the startOffset there it is failing.

Comment: I tested on chrome.. https://pasteboard.co/HtMRQWO.png startOffset = '0' appears first in sorted array. Isn't it required result?